# lapis lazuli in minecraft 1.8.8

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have the 1.8.8 updated Minecraft Console edition. In the previous version, lapis lazuli, was highly prevalent, on par with red stone or something. Since the update, I have not found nearly as much. (4 blocks total) I have found 5 times that in diamonds. I am playing in the level of bedrock to + 50 above bedrock, and I haven't found hardly any. I am using the branch style of mining, which has been highly effective in finding everything but lapis. What happening? Has lapis become more rare in version 1.8.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli_Ore#Natural_generation

> Lapis lazuli ore is found at a depth of 31 and below. The highest concentration of lapis lazuli ore is found between levels 13 and 16. At this level the concentration is about 0.083% of all blocks (0.1013% of stone). The concentration drops linearly as one gets farther from these rows. Overall, lapis lazuli is around 1.1 times as common as diamond ore with an average of 3.43 lapis lazuli per chunk.

If you are chunk mining, I would recommend moving to another chunk.

Comment: Im branching through multiple chunks. I will try moving elsewhere though.